# Chat application: .NET, Mongodb - AMQP or Node.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I was assigned with the task of writing something like a chat server recently and I m having a trouble deciding on the tech stack. I will use ASP.NET MVC for the main app layer and I think I ve already decided on using mongodb for a portion of the data storage (requiring geolocation features and bounding box queries so could really go with MSSQL).

This part works fine for now, but again I m only prototyping at this stage.

A major part of this system is to allow p2p communication between users. For the moment I am using a saas app for pushing data to the mobile device but this is only a temporary solution. The cost is simply too high to support the number of concurrent connections we are looking for (a few thousand), so we are looking to roll out our own solution.

We have narrowed it down to either using a node.js app or using an amqp solution like rabbitmq (but we would still use mongodb as the chat storage layer though).

Can anyone help with this? what would be the most cost effective solution to provide a resilient, scalable chat feature to the users?

Thanks,
Yannis

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR

Comment: What kind of performance should I expect from SignalR from a standard  production-level server? How easy does that scale? I dont understand why my question was closed, quoting: "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise". Thats exactly what I asked here. Experience w.r.t. scalability of suggested solutions. Never meant to start a fanboy topic.

Comment: There isn't something that could even be considered a definitive answer to this.  If you are in the MS stack, then SignalR is probably your best bet, either using an MQ and/or MongoDB on the backend.  NodeJS is really nice, and socket.io is more mature than SignalR at this point in time...  If you can have a fixed record size, you could set a limit, and use MongoDB as a queue

Comment: Well I disagree. There are hundreds of thousands of questions in SO where people express opinion based on their past experience. I am not looking for someone to decide the stack for me. I m just looking for experiences of people using each tech solution so that I can make a decision with more information at hand.